# Help with a Validation Rule firing

Tags: validation-rule

I need to stop all users from updating a Case record that has a current Status = Request Approved, UNLESS all the following is met:
The running user has a Profile = **HelpDesk User** OR **System Administrator**
AND The running user is only updating the Status field

Here's what I currently have but it's still allowing the HelpDesk user to update ANY field on the Case and it should only allow them to update the Status

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Request Approved'),
NOT (ISCHANGED(Status)),
$Profile.Name <> 'NVP HelpDesk User',
NOT($Profile.Name = 'NVP HelpDesk User')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Request Approved"), 
    OR( 
       NOT(ISCHANGED(Status)), 
       NOT(OR(
              $Profile.Name = "HelpDesk User", 
              $Profile.Name = "System Administrator")
             )
          )
 )
```

This formula checks if the case status is Request Approved, and if so, it checks if either the status field is not changed or the running user does not have a profile of HelpDesk User or System Administrator. If both conditions are true, the formula returns true and the validation rule fires. If either condition is false, the formula returns false and the validation rule does not fire.

Comment: @Tushar--that worked! Looks like the "OR" is what I needed. Thanks so much!